# Clutchless Shifting - Wears Rings or Assembly?

Tags: manual-transmission

What gets worn, the synchronizer rings or the assembly?

If both get worn, what are the specifics of that?

And how long can they typically be expected to last (miles) if most driving is performed without the clutch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most designs the whole synchronizer system wears when the shaft speeds are not matched on a shift. This includes three or four parts. The sliding hub: This is the part moved by the driver by a linkage. The synchronizer clutch hub: A part that catches a cone on the gear. The gear is also worn because it has the   synchronizer engagement teeth. In most designs the clutch as a spring that also wears. When repairs are performed all worn gears and synchronizer kits are replaced at significant expense.

As to the how long it will last question. That entirely depends on the skill of the driver. Some can match clutch shafts well resulting in less wear. Most cannot match the speeds and cause rather rapid damage.

Comment: Do any of those parts wear significant faster than the others?

Comment: The shift hub and gear take the brunt of the wear, both about the same amount.